# After running the script, browser hangs up. Other browsers works

Tags: php, browser

I wrote a script that exports data from database and then put it to XML file. Script works in infinite while loop with proper break statement (after task is done). Task takes to 10 minuts. When I make http request to start a job, browser which i'm using completly freezes - not only requested URL but whole host. In the same time with other browsers I can browse the webpage which contains my script.

Snippet of my PHP script:

```
while(true)
{
    if($i === $z)
    {
        break;
    }

    foreach((array)$this->project as $project)
    {
        makeYourJob();
        usleep(1000000);
        $z++;
    }
    usleep(2000000);
}
```

Script is invoked with this jquery code (I type address of HTML page which contains this code):

```
    $.get("cron.php");
```

Also I tried to type cron.php in URL bar and browser hangs up too. Why browser which runs the script freezes? How to avoid this?

EDIT:
Making a simple get/post request by ajax or user will not resolve problem. This post isn't a duplicate. Here is a solution:

```
exec("wget http://www.domain.com/scrip_name.php > /dev/null &");
```

Comment: why do you use while(true) and not something like while($i !== $z)?

Comment: `while(true)` - theres your problem.

Comment: Why don't you run it as an actual cron script from your control panel and eliminate the timeout setting so that the cron browser (if using wget) will run it rather than your own browser?

Comment: @PAM: May I ask you: Why not? Can you explain why you *think* this would be wrong?

Comment: I need to run this script from cron and from browser too.

Comment: While(cond) statement does not changing anything. Browser is hanged.

Comment: I will try proc_open tomorow.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, the if statement which breaks the infinite loop is not being invoked.

Can you check the initialization values of $i and $z? Also, === checks if the 2 variables are of the same type AND of the same value. I'd suggest you check the type of $i and $z variables.

Comment: It's just a snippet. $i is int and is set to 0. If statement is reached for sure.